# How to reset Available Software Sites to factory defaults in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse

Probably I have a problem with Eclipse software sites. So, I went to software sites and delete all of them:

[image]

Now, how to enter default sites here?

Note, that I don't want to mottle them one by one.

Comment: Download fresh eclipse, select all sites and click on `Export...` button. Then import.

Answer (score 1):

Only those 2 I think :

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4

[source](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites)